# How to read hive table along with metadata in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am not able to read a hive table along with its metadata using pyspark

I am creating the hive table accurately I think

Setup:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

data1 = [(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(5,6,7)]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(data1,schema = 'a int,b int,c int')
parquet_path = './bucket_test_parquet1'
```

Now, checking the tables with `DESCRIBE`

```
df1.write.bucketBy(5,"a").format("parquet").saveAsTable('df',path=parquet_path,mode='overwrite')
spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED df").show(100)
output:
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|            col_name|           data_type|comment|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|                   a|                 int|   null|
|                   b|                 int|   null|
|                   c|                 int|   null|
|                    |                    |       |
|# Detailed Table ...|                    |       |
|            Database|             default|       |
|               Table|                  df|       |
|               Owner|               nitin|       |
|        Created Time|Tue Feb 01 09:05:...|       |
|         Last Access|             UNKNOWN|       |
|          Created By|         Spark 3.2.0|       |
|                Type|            EXTERNAL|       |
|            Provider|             parquet|       |
|         Num Buckets|                   5|       |
|      Bucket Columns|               [`a`]|       |
|        Sort Columns|                  []|       |
|            Location|file:/home/nitin/...|       |
|       Serde Library|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|         InputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|        OutputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

```
read_parquet1 = spark.read.format("parquet").load(parquet_path,header=True)
read_parquet1.createOrReplaceTempView("rp1")
read_parquet1 = spark.table("rp1")
spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED rp1").show(100)
output:
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
|       a|      int|   null|
|       b|      int|   null|
|       c|      int|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+
```

As you can see the metadata is not getting read in when I am reading in the table from the disk. Can you help me read the table so that I have metadata along with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a table schema for an datapath you might as well do this:

read_parquet1 = spark.read.format("parquet").load(parquet_path,header=True)
read_parquet1.PrintSchema() -- This would give you your desired result.

The problem with your code is that when you notice the first code of your, you have written the data to a location and asked for its schema, whereas in the second case, you are reading from a location creating a temp table and asking the temp table for its definition. Ideally you should be asking the datapath for its Schema as in my code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).